MySQL Query takes too much time with SUM & GROUP BY
It significantly reduce the time to below 1 second when I removed sum & group by parts from the query.
It takes 2 minutes to execute the above query, and each table has only 95000 rows except the tender table, which has about 100 records. How can I optimize this query?
relevant indexes have been created & I have linked them at the bottom
'' = '' or TT.Currency_Id ='' are placeholders
Executing Query as below.
select
        RTI.Terminal_Number as TERMINAL_NUMBER,
        RTI.Transaction_Number as TRANSACTION_NUMBER,
        RTI.Completed_Date_Time as DATE_TIME,
        PS.User_Id as USER_ID,
        TT.Customer_Id as CUSTOMER_ID,
        TT.Customer_Surname as CUSTOMER_SURNAME,
        T.Description as TENDER_TYPE,
        sum(PS.Sales_Quantity) as SALES_QUANTITY,
        sum(-PS.Returns_Quantity) as RETURNS_QUANTITY,
        sum(-TT.Value) as VALUE,
        sum(PS.Sales_Value) as SALES_VALUE,
        sum(-PS.Returns_Value) as RETURNS_VALUE,
        sum(PS.Tax_Value) as TAX_VALUE,
        TT.Card_Number_Mangled as CARD_NUMBER
from
        ProductSales PS
inner join RetailTransactionIds RTI on
        PS.Transaction_Key = RTI.Transaction_Key
inner join TenderTransactions TT on
        TT.Transaction_Key = RTI.Transaction_Key
inner join Tenders T on
        T.Tender_Id = TT.Tender_Id
        and T.Group_Id=TT.Tender_Group_Id
        and T.Group_Hierarchy_Id=TT.Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id
where
        ('' = ''
        or TT.Currency_Id ='')
        and ('' = ''
        or RTI.Location_Id ='')
        and ('' = ''
        or PS.User_Id = '')
        and ('' = ''
        or RTI.Device_Id ='')
        and ('' = ''
        or TT.Tender_Id = '')
        and ('' = ''
        or TT.Customer_Id = '')
        and ('' = ''
        or TT.Card_Number = '')
        and ('' = ''
        or TT.Card_Scheme_Id = '')
group by
        RTI.Terminal_Number,
        RTI.Transaction_Number,
        RTI.Completed_Date_Time,
        TT.Customer_Id,
        TT.Customer_Surname,
        T.Description,
        TT.Card_Number_Mangled,
        PS.User_Id,
        PS.Sales_Quantity;

Productsale table indexes

retailTransactionId table indexes

tendertransaction table indexes

Explain on the query

Productsales table definition
CREATE TABLE `productsales` (
  `Entity_Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Last_Updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transaction_Key` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Line_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salesperson_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hour` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Minute` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product_Description` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `MMGroup_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `MMGroup_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `MMGroup_Variant_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `MMGroup_Variant_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sales_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sales_Quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Discounts_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Promotions_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price_Overrides_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Returns_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Returns_Quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tax_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tax_Exempt_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tax_Exempt_Reason_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Values_Include_Tax` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tax_Rate_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tax_Rate_Effective_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Receipt_Return` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reference_Number` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price_Change_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Item_Type` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Orders_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Orders_Quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tender_Description` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `productsales_Transaction_Key_desc_IDX` (`Transaction_Key`,`Line_Number`,`Tender_Description`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ProductSalesIdDescIndex` (`Product_Id`,`Product_Description`),
  KEY `ProductSalesDateNumberIndex` (`Date_Number`),
  KEY `productsales_Transaction_Key_IDX` (`Transaction_Key`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `productsales_User_Id_IDX` (`User_Id`,`Sales_Quantity`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `productsales_Tender_Description_IDX` (`Tender_Description`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `productsales_Sales_Value_IDX` (`Sales_Value`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

Productsales table definition
CREATE TABLE `retailtransactionids` (
  `Entity_Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Last_Updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transaction_Key` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Transaction_Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terminal_Number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Device_Id` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Region_Group_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Region_Group_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transaction_Id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Application_Id` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Base_Currency_Id` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Date_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Date_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Trading_Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed_Trading_Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date_Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Trading_Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Trading_Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `RetailTransactionIdsKeyIndex` (`Transaction_Key`),
  KEY `RetailTransactionIdsAppTrans` (`Application_Id`,`Transaction_Id`),
  KEY `RetailTransIdsTransIdIdx` (`Transaction_Id`),
  KEY `Retailtransids_Locatedate` (`Location_Id`,`Completed_Date_Time`),
  KEY `RetailTransIdsComplteAndLocId` (`Completed_Date_Time`,`Location_Id`),
  KEY `RetailTransIds_Session` (`Location_Id`,`Terminal_Number`,`Completed_Date_Time`),
  KEY `retailtransactionids_Terminal_Number_IDX` (`Terminal_Number`,`Transaction_Number`,`Completed_Date_Time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `retailtransactionids_TermNum_TranNum_IDX` (`Terminal_Number`,`Transaction_Number`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

TenderTransactions table definition
CREATE TABLE `tendertransactions` (
  `Entity_Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Last_Updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transaction_Key` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Line_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hour` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Minute` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tender_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tender_Group_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tender_Type` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Currency_Id` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Base_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Exchange_Rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Authorising_User_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Number` varchar(22) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Number_Hashed` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Number_Mangled` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Encrypted_Data` varchar(350) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Key_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Type_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Type_Group_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Type_Group_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Id` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Surname` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Postcode` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Merchant_Id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Acquirer_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Acquirer_Group_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Acquirer_Group_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Change` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Account_Id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surcharge_Value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Over_Payment_Amount` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Entry_Method` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Coupon_Manufacturer_Id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Coupon_Manufacturer_Ref_Id` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Card_Scheme_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `TenderTransactionsKeyIndex` (`Transaction_Key`,`Line_Number`),
  KEY `TenderTransCardNumberIndex` (`Card_Number`),
  KEY `TenderTransCardNumberHashIndex` (`Card_Number_Hashed`),
  KEY `TenderTransBaseValueIndex` (`Base_Value`),
  KEY `TenderTransUserIdIndex` (`User_Id`),
  KEY `TenderTransCustomerIdIndex` (`Customer_Id`),
  KEY `TenderTransValueIndex` (`Value`),
  KEY `TenderTransDateNumber` (`Date_Number`),
  KEY `tendertransactions_Transaction_Key_IDX` (`Transaction_Key`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tendertransactions_Customer_Id_IDX` (`Customer_Id`,`Customer_Surname`,`Card_Number_Mangled`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tendertransactions_Tender_Id_IDX` (`Tender_Id`,`Tender_Group_Id`,`Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tendertransactions_covering_IDX` (`Transaction_Key`,`Tender_Id`,`Tender_Group_Id`,`Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tendertransactions_Currency_Id_IDX` (`Currency_Id`,`Tender_Id`,`Customer_Id`,`Card_Number`,`Card_Scheme_Id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

Tenders table definition
CREATE TABLE `tenders` (
  `ID` varchar(44) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Entity_Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Tender_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Tender_Type` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Description` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Group_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Group_Type` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Group_Hierarchy_Id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `Is_Auto_Banked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Auto_Picked_Up` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Banking_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Cashup_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Currency_Purchase_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Float_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Pickup_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_Spot_Check_Tender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Last_Updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `XML` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TendersKeyIndex` (`Tender_Id`,`Group_Id`,`Group_Type`,`Group_Hierarchy_Id`),
  KEY `TendersTenderTypeIndex` (`Tender_Type`),
  KEY `TendersUpdatedIndex` (`Last_Updated`),
  KEY `TendersTimestampIndex` (`Timestamp`),
  KEY `tenders_Tender_Id_IDX` (`Tender_Id`,`Group_Id`,`Group_Hierarchy_Id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tenders_Description_IDX` (`Description`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;


Please run show create table tableName for all of your related tables in text format. What are '' = '' for ?

'It significantly reduce the time..removed sum & group by  ' - how man rows were returned?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please read this, then [edit] your question.

@ErgestBasha '' = '' are used for placeholders. those values will be assigned on runtime

@P.Salmon , 95 000 rows were returned

@O.Jones updated the question details.

How big are the tables?  (SHOW TABLE STATUS)

One way to speed up the query is to have 3 tables in a subquery, then look up T.Description as TENDER_TYPE after doing the GROUP BY, something like this:
SELECT subq.*, T.Description as TENDER_TYPE
    FROM (
        select  RTI.Terminal_Number as TERMINAL_NUMBER, RTI.Transaction_Number as TRANSACTION_NUMBER,
                RTI.Completed_Date_Time as DATE_TIME, PS.User_Id as USER_ID,
                TT.Customer_Id as CUSTOMER_ID, TT.Customer_Surname as CUSTOMER_SURNAME,
                T.Description as TENDER_TYPE, sum(PS.Sales_Quantity) as SALES_QUANTITY,
                sum(-PS.Returns_Quantity) as RETURNS_QUANTITY, sum(-TT.Value) as VALUE,
                sum(PS.Sales_Value) as SALES_VALUE, sum(-PS.Returns_Value) as RETURNS_VALUE,
                sum(PS.Tax_Value) as TAX_VALUE, TT.Card_Number_Mangled as CARD_NUMBER
            from  ProductSales PS
            inner join  RetailTransactionIds RTI  ON PS.Transaction_Key = RTI.Transaction_Key
            inner join  TenderTransactions TT  ON TT.Transaction_Key = RTI.Transaction_Key
            inner join  Tenders T  ON T.Tender_Id = TT.Tender_Id
              and  T.Group_Id=TT.Tender_Group_Id
              and  T.Group_Hierarchy_Id=TT.Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id
            where  ...
            group by  RTI.Terminal_Number, RTI.Transaction_Number, RTI.Completed_Date_Time,
                TT.Customer_Id, TT.Customer_Surname, TT.Card_Number_Mangled,
                PS.User_Id, PS.Sales_Quantity
      ) AS subq
    JOIN Tenders T  ON T.Tender_Id = subq.Tender_Id
              and  T.Group_Id = subq.Tender_Group_Id
              and  T.Group_Hierarchy_Id = subq.Tender_Group_Hierarchy_Id

If the data is much larger than innodb_buffer_pool_size, there could be a caching problem.  (The above rewrite will help somewhat.)
Many columns have datatypes that are bigger than necessary.
The WHERE clause is weird -- ('' = '' OR ...) is always TRUE; hopefully the Optimizer is smart enough to realize that.
You have no PRIMARY KEY on one of the tables.  It does have a UNIQUE key, but that cannot be promoted to PRIMARY because the columns are NULLable.
Usually it is inefficient to split DATETIME into multiple columns.
